# Запрос с whereClause retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Необходимо получить 1 экземпляр объекта из БД в Backendless через Retrofit. Поиск по первичному ключу (Логину)

Интерфейс ретрофита описан так:

**BackendlessAPI.java**

```
@GET("data/Users?where")
    Call<User> getUserByLogin(@Query(value = "login", encoded = true) String login);
```

Пытаюсь затестить метод:

```
    @Test
        public void testApiGetUsernameByLogin() throws Exception {
            Retrofit backendlessRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            BackendlessAPI backendlessAPI = backendlessRetrofit.create(BackendlessAPI.class);
            System.out.println(backendlessAPI.getUserByLogin("timuruktus").execute().body())
};
```

Консоль выдает это:

```
null

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Вот документация от Backendless:
https://backendless.com/docs/rest/doc.html#data_search_with_where_clause

Пример БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

POJO объект:

**User.java**

```
public class User {

    private String login;
    private String vkId;
    private String name;
    private String objectId;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String login, String vkId, String name, String objectId) {
        this.login = login;
        this.vkId = vkId;
        this.name = name;
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getVkId() {
        return vkId;
    }

    public void setVkId(String vkId) {
        this.vkId = vkId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

}
```

Более подробная информация их консоли:

```
Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=https://api.backendless.com/****/*****/data/Users?where=&login=timuruktus}
```

Получается, что после `where=` идет амперсанд, а он там не нужен! Как при использовании аннотации `Query` можно убрать амперсанд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аннотация Query используется для указания имени для http-параметра

API:

```
@GET("data/Users")
Call<List<User>> getUserByCondition(@Query("where") String condition);
```

Запрос:

```
backendlessAPI.getUserByCondition("login='timuruktus'").execute().body()
```

Comment: Все работает. Запрос надо формировать так: `backendlessAPI.getUserByCondition("login='timuruktus'").execute().body()` . Кроме того, сам метод getUserByCondition не может возвращать Call<User> , он возвращает только Call<List<User>> : `@GET("data/Users")
    Call<List<User>> getUserByCondition(@Query("where") String condition);`